# How do you show the hours of the day using the Calendar Control in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make an employee roster schedule in ASP.NET, in C#.

The visual studio 'Calendar' control shows the days of each month by default. Is there a way to display the hours of the day?

For example, when you go into the 'Day' view of Google Calendar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var dateHour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        lblHour.Text = dateHour.ToString();
```

try this, i hope that helps

Comment: This doesn't change the way the 'Calendar' control displays things. I think the author of the question wants the Calendar-control to 'zoom into the day'. It don't think that is possible by the way.